# Mysql dump for all tables with limit1

Tags: limit, mysql, record

Is it possible to take `dump` of all tables in a `mysql` database with single record (limit 1)?Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
mysqldump db_name --where="1 limit 1" > backup-file.sql
```